# check if a specific document exists or no , Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm very new at flutter and firebase and i was trying to build an app that displays both users posts to each other if they have "friendship" similar to what we see on facebook,

however when i try to check for a document using the logic below :

b

```
ool friendship =false;
  checkConnection(String target) async{

   await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(loggedUser.phoneNumber).collection("friendship").where("phoneNumber", isEqualTo: target).get().then((value) {
      if(value.docs.first.exists)
        friendship=true;
        else
        friendship=false;
    });

  }
```

> and then using streambuilder to display posts

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return snapshot.data.docs.length == 0
                ? noPosts()
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot currentDoc = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                      checkConnection(currentDoc["by"]);
                         friendship?singlePostWidget(currentDoc["by"],currentDoc["context"]):SizedBox();
                    });
          }
```

the error which i'm getting is :

> E/flutter (15767): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(242)] Dart
> Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element, stack trace: #0
> List.first (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:332:5) E/flutter
> (15767): #1      _CommunityState.checkConnection.
> (package:connect/Screens/Account/Community/Community.dart:119:21)
> E/flutter (15767): #2      _RootZone.runUnary
> (dart:async/zone.dart:1612:54) E/flutter (15767): #3
> _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18) E/flutter (15767): #4
> Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45) E/flutter (15767): #5
> Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)
> E/flutter (15767): #6      Future._completeWithValue
> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:539:5) E/flutter (15767): #7
> _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:254:13) E/flutter (15767): #8      Query.get
> (package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart) E/flutter (15767):
>  E/flutter (15767):

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `await` and `then` together. Delete await from first code block.

await is meant to interrupt the process flow until the async method has finished. then however does not interrupt the process flow (meaning the next instructions will be executed) but enables you to run code when the async method is finished.